# Cut of the cube projected to the rectangle

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projection-matrices

I have a 3D euclidean space. Somewhere in this space is positioned unit cube, that is aligned with the axes of the 3D geometry. Assume that there is arbitrarily placed 2D square in the space that must not be aligned anyhow with the geometry, lets even say its convex polygon given by arbitrary points A, B, C, D.

Is there a fast algorithm to find the volume of the intersection of the pyramid 0, A, B, C, D with the cube?

Is there a chance to simplify the things if I know that A, B, C, D is rectangle relative to some (projective) plane, not necessary aligned with the axes? So that there exists camera matrix for camera centered at 0 such that I would like to find volume of the cut through the cube that gets projected on $[A, A+ \delta A]$ and $[B, B+ \delta B]$ for camera matrix/projective plane.

Comment: The term "volume" is ambiguous : Do you mean the numerical volume (in $m^3$ for example) or the 3D shape with coordinates of extremal points ?

Comment: By volume I mean physical quantity and I am OK with single number even if I don't have these coordinates. If I had centroid, that would be beneficial but not necessary.

Comment: Do we agree that in fact we have to add the volume of (at most) 3 pyramidal shapes, one for each of the 3 "active" faces of the cube ?

Comment: I am aware of "pyramid counting algorithm". Although I think in general if the intersection involves whole cube or even two opposite vertices, we would have to add 3 pyramidal shapes and subtract 3 others. So let's say we reduce the problem to finding polygonal shape of the cube face cut, complexity somehow increases 6 times and we need fast algorithm to find surface of the cut, my cube is part of the volume grid and rectangle is the part of another grid and I need to find cuts for them all.

Comment: When you say " to find the volume of the intersection of the pyramid", by volume, do you mean a shape or a number (in $m^3$ for example) ?

Comment: When I say volume I mean a number. For example a volume of the cube defined by corner $x$ and orthogonal vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ to other corners such that the cube corners are $x$, $x+v_1$, $x+v_2$ , $x+v_3$ , , $x+v_1+v_2+v_3$ would have a volume $|v_1|*|v_2|*|v_3|$. I am also interested in center of mass of such object that in this case would be $x+v_1/2+v_2/2+v_3/2$.

Comment: I think that you should give a precise example on an unambiguous figure; Personnally, as you have seen by my answer, I have lost my time trying to answer a question that I had misunderstood, and I will not revise it unless I am sure to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your present issue (finding the polygonal shape of the cube face cut) :

[image]

We assume that the cube's vertices are

$$O(0,0,0), \ \ A(1,0,0), \ \ B(0,1,0), \ \ C(0,0,1), \cdots$$

For each vertex $V(x,y,z)$  of your polygon, consider the three intersection points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ of line $OV$ with the three planes with equations $x=1$, $y=1$, $z=1$ resp.

Then simply keep the one with smallest length $OP_k$.

Remark : The coordinates of intersection points are :

$$P_1(1,y/x,z/x), \ \ \ P_2(x/y,1,z/y), \ \ \ P_3(x/z,y/z,1) \tag{1}$$

assuming $x,y,z \neq 0.$

Therefore, finding the smallest length is in fact done by comparing

$$1/x, 1/y, 1/z$$

If $1/x$ is the smallest, then it is $P_1$, etc.

(Figure done with a Matlab program).

Comment: No comment about this solution ?

Comment: First I would need to locate "vertices of my polygon" and the cube does not need to have one face at 0. So I am still interested in the solution but what I need to find is a intersection of a pyramid, not a cone, with a rectangle given by (r_1, r_2, r_3), (r_1, r_2, r_3) + a, (r_1, r_2, r_3)+a+b, (r_1+a, r_2+b, r_3)+b, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are general nonzero vectors. Then I would like to find what is the surface of the intersection and maybe even where is its center of mass.

Comment: The problem is therefore related to the https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894941/cutting-ball-problem where I don't cut ball but randomly oriented rectangle in the space and finding its surface area and center of mass.

Comment: I will think about what you just wrote.